# Horizontal lines in Firefox

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, intel-graphics, lenovo, visual-artifacts

I've recently got a Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd Gen and installed Xubuntu 16.04. I've noticed that sometimes horizontal glitchy lines appear.

[image: screen]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got this problem too. There was a similar issue when I first got this laptop (maybe with 15.04?) but not only with FF, with every app, but this is different, only on FF.

Answer (score 1):

[Taking the advice from this link worked for me.](https://nathanpfry.com/fix-video-tearing-xubuntu-compton/).

As a TL;DR, it seems that xfce4 uses a pretty garbage, un-maintained compositor to render windows. Compton is a much better option. Install compton, and then add this text to the `~/.compton.conf` file:

```
backend = "glx";
paint-on-overlay = true;
glx-no-stencil = true;
glx-no-rebind-pixmap = true;
vsync = "none";
shadow = true;
no-dock-shadow = true;
no-dnd-shadow = true;
clear-shadow = true;
shadow-radius = 7;
shadow-offset-x = -7;
shadow-offset-y = -7;
shadow-exclude = [
"! name~=''",
"name = 'Notification'",
"name = 'Docky'",
"name = 'Plank'",
"name = 'xfce4-notifyd'",
"name *= 'SMPlayer'",
"name *= 'compton'",
"name *= 'Firefox'",
"name *= 'Chrome'",
"name *= 'Thunderbird'",
"name *= 'Deluge'",
"class_g = 'Conky'",
"class_g ?= 'Notify-osd'",
"class_g ?= 'Xfce4-notifyd'",
"class_g ?= 'Xfce4-power-manager'"
];
fading = true;
fade-delta = 4;
fade-in-step = 0.03;
fade-out-step = 0.03;

detect-client-opacity = true;

wintypes:
{
tooltip = { fade = true; shadow = false; };
};
```